# Android Studio new Project throws Errors

Tags: android, android-studio, compiler-errors, installation

The last days I wanted to get started to Android Studios so I downloaded it. During the installation process it wanted me to download a jdk and sent me to this page --> http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html where I downloaded the jdk 7u80 64 bit version. Until here all was good, but when I started a new projekt and wanted to run it, it told me that there were already some errors in it.

i wanted to add some pictures about the error, but my reputation is to low. So lock at this link where a guy had the same problem as i. -->
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=183149
It is the 16th entry at this page. The problem is that at this part of code

```
parent="android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse"
```

the "Inverse" is not found, and in another row it doesnt find "Colored".
I read at some pages that a problem could be that the program doesnt find java so i set the system environment variable, but this doesnt work.There were some other "solutions" but dont understood all they talked because im new to android studio. so if somebody could help me that would be great.

**EDIT:**

**Logs:**

2015-08-21 16:30:35,495 [ 310309]   WARN - options.ex.ConfigurableWrapper - XML does not provide id for class com.android.tools.idea.run.CloudTestingConfigurable 
2015-08-21 16:30:35,531 [ 310345]   WARN - ConfigurableExtensionPointUtil - Can't find parent for project.propCompiler (Compiler) 
2015-08-21 16:30:42,831 [ 317645]   INFO - llij.help.impl.HelpManagerImpl - Failed to load help set from 'jar:file:///C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\help\ideahelp.jar!/idea/Help.hs' 
javax.help.HelpSetException: Could not parse
Got an IOException (C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\help\ideahelp.jar (Das System kann den angegebenen Pfad nicht finden))
Parsing failed for null
    at javax.help.HelpSet.(HelpSet.java:154)
    at com.intellij.help.impl.HelpManagerImpl.loadHelpSet(HelpManagerImpl.java:174)
    at com.intellij.help.impl.HelpManagerImpl.createHelpSet(HelpManagerImpl.java:148)
    at com.intellij.help.impl.HelpManagerImpl.invokeHelp(HelpManagerImpl.java:57)
    at com.intellij.ide.actions.HelpTopicsAction.actionPerformed(HelpTopicsAction.java:26)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.performActionDumbAware(ActionUtil.java:182)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionButton.actionPerformed(ActionButton.java:162)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionButton.performAction(ActionButton.java:126)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionButton.processMouseEvent(ActionButton.java:303)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6281)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4872)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:747)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$300(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:706)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:704)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:720)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:718)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:717)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:734)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:565)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:382)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
2015-08-21 16:34:25,881 [ 540695]   INFO - tools.idea.ddms.adb.AdbService - Initializing adb using: C:\Users\Florin\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe, client support = true 
2015-08-21 16:34:30,749 [ 545563]   INFO - tools.idea.ddms.adb.AdbService - Successfully connected to adb 
2015-08-21 16:34:30,787 [ 545601]   INFO - a.gradle.invoker.GradleInvoker - About to execute Gradle tasks: [:app:assembleDebug] 
2015-08-21 16:34:30,807 [ 545621]   INFO - s.plugins.gradle.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_80 
2015-08-21 16:34:30,810 [ 545624]   INFO - util.EmbeddedDistributionPaths - Looking for embedded Maven repo at 'C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\m2repository' 
2015-08-21 16:34:30,813 [ 545627]   INFO - util.EmbeddedDistributionPaths - Looking for embedded Gradle distribution at 'C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\gradle-2.4' 
2015-08-21 16:34:30,814 [ 545628]   INFO - util.EmbeddedDistributionPaths - Found embedded Gradle 2.4 
2015-08-21 16:34:30,814 [ 545628]   INFO - a.gradle.invoker.GradleInvoker - Build command line options: [--configure-on-demand, -Pandroid.injected.invoked.from.ide=true, --init-script, C:\Users\Florin\AppData\Local\Temp\asLocalRepo4.gradle] 
2015-08-21 16:34:30,814 [ 545628]   INFO - .project.GradleExecutionHelper - Passing command-line args to Gradle Tooling API: [--configure-on-demand, -Pandroid.injected.invoked.from.ide=true, --init-script, C:\Users\Florin\AppData\Local\Temp\asLocalRepo4.gradle] 
2015-08-21 16:34:34,496 [ 549310]   INFO - indexing.UnindexedFilesUpdater - Indexable files iterated in 121 ms 
2015-08-21 16:36:22,552 [ 657366]   INFO - a.gradle.invoker.GradleInvoker - About to execute Gradle tasks: [:app:assembleDebug] 
2015-08-21 16:36:22,583 [ 657397]   INFO - s.plugins.gradle.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_80 
2015-08-21 16:36:22,598 [ 657412]   INFO - util.EmbeddedDistributionPaths - Looking for embedded Maven repo at 'C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\m2repository' 
2015-08-21 16:36:22,598 [ 657412]   INFO - util.EmbeddedDistributionPaths - Looking for embedded Gradle distribution at 'C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\gradle-2.4' 
2015-08-21 16:36:22,598 [ 657412]   INFO - util.EmbeddedDistributionPaths - Found embedded Gradle 2.4 
2015-08-21 16:36:22,598 [ 657412]   INFO - a.gradle.invoker.GradleInvoker - Build command line options: [--configure-on-demand, -Pandroid.injected.invoked.from.ide=true, --init-script, C:\Users\Florin\AppData\Local\Temp\asLocalRepo5.gradle] 
2015-08-21 16:36:22,598 [ 657412]   INFO - .project.GradleExecutionHelper - Passing command-line args to Gradle Tooling API: [--configure-on-demand, -Pandroid.injected.invoked.from.ide=true, --init-script, C:\Users\Florin\AppData\Local\Temp\asLocalRepo5.gradle] 
2015-08-21 16:36:25,645 [ 660459]   INFO - indexing.UnindexedFilesUpdater - Indexable files iterated in 51 ms

**Console Output:**

Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72300Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42300Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name \u0027android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"C:\Users\Florin\AndroidStudioProjects\MyFirstApp\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\23.0.0\res\values-v23\values-v23.xml","position":{"startLine":1}}],"original":""}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name \u0027android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored\u0027.","sources":[{"file":"C:\Users\Florin\AndroidStudioProjects\MyFirstApp\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\23.0.0\res\values-v23\values-v23.xml","position":{"startLine":1}}],"original":""}

FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

  > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\Florin\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\23.0.0\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 2.839 secs

Comment: Edit your question with the log errors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The accepted answer did not solve my proplem. Instead:

1. Installed Android SDK 23 in Android SDK Manager
2. in `build.gradle`:

Changed this:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "net.ipronto.testandroid2"
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 22
```

To

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "net.ipronto.testandroid2"
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 23
```

And problem resolved. I have also installed SDK version 23 in Android SDK Manager.

Answer (score 0):

I have got the same problem when my machine was replaced with a new one.

The following steps seem to solve the problem for me  (from https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=183122).

- delete the "Android SDK Build-tools 23" from the SDK manager
- In the SDK folder (actual folder) go to   sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7
- remove 23.0.0 folder
- in the same folder, open maven-metadata.xml and delete the line <.version>23.0.0<./version>, then save it.
- clean and rebuild